# how to calculate the limit number in oracle bulk collect for best performance

Tags: oracle11g

how to calculate the limit number in oracle bulk collect for best performance

Answer (score 2):

The trade offs in choosing any particular bulk collection limit are between memory consumption (high limit) and context switching (low limit).  At the low end context switching related performance issues will dominate.  For example with a limit of one, you are no better off than when you didn't do bulk collection.  With a limit of 100 performance issues related to context switches will be reduced to 1% of what they were with no bulk collection.  Upping the limit to 200 will only save you .5% in context switching related performance issues, but you'll have doubled the amount of memory needed to support the bulk collection.  The upper bound on the limit will be dependent on the amount of memory available, the size of each logical record returned, and the amount of memory being consumed concurrently by yours and others processes.

Most of the time adequate performance improvement will be achieved with limits in the range of 50 to 200, and unless the logical record sizes are large, limits in those ranges shouldn't be an issue for available memory unless your system is fairly memory constrained and/or you have a large number of concurrent bulk collection processes going on.